# Qt Mouse Buttons

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt for a while, there is some things i'm doing that are working, but I don't understand why, like this one :

```
(event->buttons() & Qt::MiddleButton)
```

this would return `true` when the MiddleButton is pressed, but my problem is the syntax, Qt says that Qt::MiddleButton has a value of 4 so as a boolean is would always return true, so that means that the expression is equivalent to this : `(event->buttons())` ... And that's not logical neither ... Can someone please explain ??

Comment: the `&`operator is a **bitwise AND** operator. the code you show return '0' if the middlebutton is not pressed otherwise Qt::MiddleButton. In C/C++ a integer value different than '0' is evaluated as TRUE

Comment: Well, that's exactly what i'm saying ... since Qt::MiddleButton is and will always be different of 0, that means that it's also always true so why put `(event->buttons() & Qt::MiddleButton)` and not `event->buttons()` I don't see the logic behind this thing ...

Comment: The logic is to test if the MiddleButton is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Qt docs

```
Qt::LeftButton      0x00000001 ---> 00000001b
Qt::RightButton     0x00000002 ---> 00000010b
Qt::MiddleButton    0x00000004 ---> 00000100b
```

The rightmost column is a binary representation!
So,

```
Left+Right  --> buttons(): 3
Left+Middle --> buttons(): 5
.......
```

Then `(buttons() & Qt::MiddleButton)` test if the bit related to MiddleButton is set

```
Left+Right  --> 00000011 --> 00000011 & 00000100 = 00000000 --> FALSE 
Left+Middle --> 00000011 --> 00000101 & 00000100 = 00000100 --> TRUE
```

Comment: Ok I think i see what is it now, but what are the values that can have event->buttons() ?

Comment: All combinations of flags

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you mix logical operator `&&` with bitwise AND `&` operator. They are not the same. For example

```
100 && 010 = True  (both numbers are not 0)
100 &  010 = False (gives 0)
```

Checking for only `bool(event->buttons() == 0)` will give you `true` if there is no button pressed and `false` if **any** button is pressed. To check for a particular button, you need to use bitwise '&' operator.

Comment: yep I did mix the operators because in many other languages `&` is the logical operator and and `&&`  is the logical operator `and then`